# Explode single DataFrame row into multiple ones across Year-Month column?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to explode a dataframe row made of a "yearMonth" column into multiple rows where each one is a day of that month

this is the example. I want to go from this:

| Key | YearMonth |
| --- | --- |
| xxx | 202101 |

to this

| Key | YearMonthDay |
| --- | --- |
| xxx | 20210101 |
| xxx | 20210102 |
| xxx | ... |
| xxx | 20210131 |

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using some of the built-in spark functions that can be imported using:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{add_months, col, datediff, explode, concat, substring, lit, date_add, sequence, date_format}
```

The main idea of this solution can be described with the following steps:

1. convert the values into a date format as the first date of the month.
2. calculate the number of days in the given month.
3. create an array of days to add that will be exploded to a separate row each and will be added to the start date of the month
4. drop unnecessary columns

```
List("202010", "202011")
  .toDF("month_short")
  .withColumn("month", functions.concat(substring($"month_short", 0, 4), lit("-"), substring($"month_short", 5, 2), lit("-"),lit("01")))
  .withColumn("days_to_add", explode(sequence(lit(0), datediff(add_months($"month", 1), $"month") - 1)))
  .withColumn("day_in_month", date_format(date_add($"month", $"days_to_add"), "yyyyMMdd"))
  .drop("days_to_add","month")
  .show(false)
```

output example:

```
+-----------+------------+
|month_short|day_in_month|
+-----------+------------+
|202010     |20201001    |
|202010     |20201002    |
|202010     |20201003    |
|202010     |20201004    |
|202010     |20201005    |
|202010     |20201006    |
|202010     |20201007    |
|202010     |20201008    |
|202010     |20201009    |
|202010     |20201010    |
|202010     |20201011    |
|202010     |20201012    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below data functions to get the desired output:

```
df1=input_df.withColumn("YearMonthDay", 
F.explode(F.sequence(F.to_date(F.col("YearMonth").cast("string"), "yyyyMM"), 
F.last_day(F.to_date(F.col("YearMonth").cast("string"), "yyyyMM")))))
.drop("YearMonth")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).